# How to force a HTTP error in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

**IDE:**
Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate
**Language:** C# ASP.NET webpage (aspx)
**Problem:** Hi! I have an assignment for school and I am making a website using ASP.NET (C#) and I need to have 3 custom errors added.
I know how to force a 404 error (page not found) and a 500 error (error in code behind of the page) but I need a 3rd one and I don't know what ones I can force.

In my navigation menu I have a href to "404page.aspx" but that one doesn't exist in my solution so I get the 404 error.
In the menu I also have a href to "500error.aspx" and there I have wrong code in the code behind ("500error.aspx.cs") so I get the 500 error.

**Web.Config file:**

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="Error.aspx?error=404"/>
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="Error.aspx?error=500"/>
  <error statusCode="x" redirect="Error.aspx?error=x"/>
</customErrors>
```

**Error.aspx.cs (code behind Error.aspx) file:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LabelResult.Text = "";
            String errorcode = Request.QueryString.Get("error"); 
            if (errorcode.ToString().Equals("404"))
            {
                LabelResult.Text = "Page contains a 404 error.";
            }
            if (foutcode.ToString().Equals("500"))
            {
                LabelResult.Text = "Page contains a 500 error.";
            }

    }
```

So basically I need a 3rd HTTP error that I can force using C# or ASP.NET.

Comment: HTTP 403 is essentially telling you that you don't have permission to access a page.

Comment: @DavidG I know what the 403 does, but how do I force it?

Answer (score 5):

You either need to access a page you do not have permission to see or manually throw your own error in code behind:

```
throw new HttpException(403, "Access denied");
```

Comment: So if I make a href to a new page called "300error.aspx" and but this on the code behind on the Page_Load it will force the 403 error?

Comment: In theory yes (though I might call it `403error.aspx` rather than 300!)

Comment: Made the href to the 300error.aspx and put ur code on the Page_Load but it gives this error: "An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in CeeLearnAndDo.dll but was not handled in user code" eventho I have the error in my Web.Config

Comment: try 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: @KevinKraaijvanger I suspect it is working but your config isn't catching it. Prove it by putting the URL into Fiddler and see exactly what HTTP result you are getting.

Comment: It is working, it's your error handler that isn't being called. Try using this in your web.config: `<authentication mode="Forms"><forms loginUrl="~/Error.aspx?error=403" timeout="2880"/></authentication>`